# Replace every other line

Tags: ex-mode, ex-command

Given file *alfa.txt*:

```
10
11
12
13
```

I can remove every other line:

```
$ ex -sc 'g/^/+d' -cx alfa.txt
$ cat alfa.txt
10
12
```

However I cannot replace every other line:

```
$ ex -sc 'g/^/+s//> /' -cx alfa.txt
$ cat alfa.txt
10
> 11
> 12
> 13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround:

```
ex -sc '%s/\v(.*\n){2}/> &/|x' alfa.txt
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `\v` turn on magic
4. `x` save and close

Comment: It adds a newline at the end of the file. Also when `alfa.txt` has `1, 3, 5 , ...` lines the last line is ignored since it doesn't match.

Comment: @JairLopez thank you for the comment. Did you have a better solution?

Comment: No. I didn't. But I think your previous workaround was better.  As far as I can remember, it was `ex -sc 'g/^/s//> /|pu_|j' -cx alfa.txt`. The only drawback was the newline at the end.

Comment: @JairLopez yes that is right. However it does not scale. If you wanted every 3 lines, you would need `ex -sc 'g/^/s//> /|pu_|j|pu_|j' -cx alfa.txt`

Comment: I see. You could try `ex -sc '$pu_' -c '%s/\v(.*\n){2}/> &/' -c '$d|x'`. In that way it could work when `alfa.txt` has `1, 3, 5, ...` lines, but it still adds a newline at the end of the file.